# PlotnineAnimation with changing scales throws error: 'The fill scale of plot for frame 1 has different limits from those of the first frame.'

Tags: python, r, animation, gganimate, plotnine

I am trying to use the `gganimate` (R) equivalent, `plotnine` (python). I run into problems when one of the plots introduces a new aesthetic scale category, causing the console to throw the error: `The fill scale of plot for frame 1 has different limits from those of the first frame.`

This appears to be the result of having to produce a generator of all the plots and then stick them together - as per the plotnine documentation (https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.animation.PlotnineAnimation.html). When I use `gganimate()` the library is smart enough to know to check all the scales that will be called and print the complete scale accordingly.

I tried using `scale_fill_manual()` to force a scale onto the first plot as a way to deal with this, but it doesn't work (in R or python).

I am looking for a way around this in plotnine (if there is a way better animation module in python i can learn that if there are suggestions).

Here is a worked example:

First trying in plotnine:

```
#import modules
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.animation import PlotnineAnimation
#create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'run': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
             'x_pos': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], 
             'y_pos': [4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7], 
             'status': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'] })

#write a function that creates all the plots
def plot(x):
    df2 = df[df['run'] == x]

    p = (ggplot(df2,
               aes(x = 'x_pos', y = 'y_pos', fill = 'status'))
         + geom_point()
    )
    return(p)

#save the plots as a generator as per the plotnine docs (https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.animation.PlotnineAnimation.html)
plots = (plot(i) for i in range(1, 3))

#create the animation
animation = PlotnineAnimation(plots, interval=100, repeat_delay=500)
```

Throws the error: `PlotnineError: 'The fill scale of plot for frame 1 has different limits from those of the first frame.'`

If I do this in R, using `gganimate()`, everything works fine - I get all three color scales from the start:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('gganimate')

df <- data.frame(run = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                 x_pos = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4), 
                 y_pos = c(4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7), 
                 status = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x_pos, y = y_pos, col = status)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  transition_states(run)
```

[image]

When i try forcing the scale on the first plot it doesn't work. First in R:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(run == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x_pos, y = y_pos, col = status)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(labels = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
                     values = c('red', 'green', 'blue'))
```

The plot shows with just the two color scales - despite explicitly stating 3 in `scale_color_manual()`:

[image]

Then in Python:

```
#Filter the data frame created above
df2 = df[df['run'] == 1]

#Create the plot - stating scale_fill_manual()
p = (ggplot(df2,
        aes(x = 'x_pos', y = 'y_pos', fill = 'status'))
 + geom_point()
 + scale_fill_manual(labels = ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                    values = ['red', 'blue', 'green'])
)

#Print the plot
print(p)
```

Throws errors about the arrays being the wrong length (`ValueError: arrays must all be same length`), which makes sense: I am asking for more values and colors than are in the filtered dataset. That means that I cannot have the first frame match the second frame, which is the error i am trying to solve.

Anyone know how to make this work with `plotnine`, the way it does in `gganimate()`? Further (though less important), any ideas as to why `plotnine` takes fill for `geom_point()`, while `ggplot2` takes col for `geom_point()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you should make `status` a categorical, it is also better to be specific and set the limits of the `x` and `y` aesthetics, if you leave it up to the plotting system it may get them wrong.

In Plotnine all the key plotting shapes for `geom_point` have both the inner area and the stroke around it so you can use `fill` and `color` to target either. But this is an intricate detail that would most likely frustrate users, so when you map to the `color` and not the `fill` it sets the same colour for both. In between, Plotnine does not recognise the abbreviation `col`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.animation import PlotnineAnimation

#create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'run': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
             'x_pos': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], 
             'y_pos': [4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7], 
             'status': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'] })

# A categorical ensures that each of the sub-dataframes
# can be used to create a scale with the correct limits
df['status'] = pd.Categorical(df['status'])

#write a function that creates all the plots
def plot(x):
    df2 = df[df['run'] == x]

    p = (ggplot(df2,
               aes(x = 'x_pos', y = 'y_pos', color = 'status'))
         + geom_point()
         # Specify the limits for the x and y aesthetics
         + scale_x_continuous(limits=(df.x_pos.min(), df.x_pos.max()))
         + scale_y_continuous(limits=(df.y_pos.min(), df.y_pos.max()))
         + theme(subplots_adjust={'right': 0.85}) # Make space for the legend
        )
    return(p)


plots = (plot(i) for i in range(1, 3))

#create the animation
animation = PlotnineAnimation(plots, interval=1000, repeat_delay=500)
animation
```

Comment: My apologies for the slow reply. This project fell off my plate. This works perfectly. Thanks so much.